# generar pausa entre canciones

Tags: javascript

hola me pueden decir como puedo hacer para que cuando se termine una cancion se inicie la pausa, cada vez que se termine una cancion se coleque la pausa antes de seguir la siguiente cancion

```
<audio src="../estudio/beats/eminem.mp3" autoplay controls id="beat"></audio>
<button onclick="reproducir()">iniciar</button>
<button onclick="detener()">detener</button>
<div id="seccion"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

currentTrack = 0

beats = ['still.mp3', 'today.mp3']
pausa = "../estudio/beats/pausa.mp3"

beat = document.getElementById('beat')

beat.addEventListener('ended', function(){

nextTrack = beats[currentTrack++]
if(nextTrack){beat.setAttribute('src', pausa)}
beat.setAttribute('src', "../estudio/beats/"+nextTrack)
beat.play()
if(currentTrack == beats.length){currentTrack = 0}

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escuchando al Evento `onended` , pero cuando este se dé , llamar a `setTimeout` para ejecutar la espera, y luego asignar el nuevo audio  a reproducir

```
<audio src="audio.mp3" autoplay controls id="beat"></audio>

beats = ['still.mp3', 'today.mp3'];
var audio = document.getElementById('beat');
audio.onended = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
         audio.setAttribute('src',  beats[0]);/* primera canción*/
    }, 6000);/* 6 Segundos de Espera*/
    audio.setAttribute('src', 'pause.mp3');/* El audio pause es > 6 segundos*/
};
```

Comment: en vez de seis segundos de silencio quiero que se reprodusca el sonido de la pausa,

Comment: El sonido de pause tiene una duración mayor a 6 segundos? ya que si no , se volvería a ejecutar el evento.

Comment: tranquilo acabo de resolverlo, la pausa durabas solo 10segundos, ahora me siguiente duda, que pasaria si quisiera poner una pausa de un minuto, el numero seria muy largo como un 100000000 que cosa me recomendarias

Comment: Como el parametro  que acepta es milisegundos , podrías realizar multiplicaciones para disminuir los dígitos. por ejemplo para 1 min -> 60*1000

Comment: justo lo que pensaba hacer, sin embargo me parece extraño que no se puedan expresar minutos, a esta hora ecmaescript debio haberlo pensado